# Given Two Sorted Arrays and a Target, Return True Iff Two Elements Add Up To Target in O(logn) Time

Tags: algorithm

I cannot figure out this problem even after 3 months since receiving it in my interview, and nobody I know has been able to solve it either. The full problem is:

Given two sorted arrays of integers (`A` and `B`) and an integer target, return true if and only if `A[i]+B[j]=target` for some indices `i` and `j`. The algorithm must be `O(logn)` time and there aren't any space constraints.

I was able to come up with two solutions: a `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space one and an `O(nlogn)` time and `O(1)` space one. When trying to solve it in `O(logn)` time, I couldn't make much progress. I was thinking I could partition the arrays and treat it as a divide and conquer, but I was not sure how to select the subarrays given the target integer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem cannot be solved in faster than Θ(n) time in the worst case. Consider the following example input:

```
A = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
B = [10, 20, 31, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
target = 111
```

The correct result is "true", since 80 + 31 = 111. Generalising from this example, we can imagine an input of this form where A contains the multiples of 10 and B contains the multiples of 10 except, possibly, one element of the form 10k + 1. There is no way to tell whether B contains an element of the form 10k + 1 without checking every element of B in the worst case, so even if we know that A and B are always in this form (a special case of the original problem), an algorithm cannot give a definitely-correct answer in sub-linear time.

So either the interviewer who posed this problem was mistaken, or something has been lost in communication and the problem given by the interviewer is not the same as the problem stated here.

Comment: Wow thank you for the explanation and proof. I'm pretty sure I'm not mistaken on the problem since this was asked as a follow up to the case where the arrays are unsorted. Maybe they just wanted to see how hard I would try to solve it or maybe the interviewer truly was mistaken like you said.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Without any guarantees about the numbers themselves (beyond their ordering), it is necessary to inspect all numbers individually, resulting in `O(n)` time complexity at best.

To prove this, assume you have an algorithm that returns True/False accordingly in `O(log n)` time. Let us pick an even number `T` as our target, and populate one of the lists with all even numbers `0` to `(T-2)`. The other list, we'll initially populate with all the odd numbers `1` to `(T-1)`. This way, two elements (one from each list) will never sum to our value `T`, because an odd number plus an even will never be even.

Now, the tricky part- we'll randomly select a number from the odd-list, and replace it with itself plus one. If we pick `3` from `[1, 3, 5, 7, ...]`, we'd replace it with `4` for `[1, 4, 5, 7, ...]`. Now, this new even element **will** sum with a corresponding value in the even-list to make `T`, changing the answer from `False` to `True`. Our hypothetical algorithm would need to be able to detect this change in `O(log n)` time. However, I could have altered any of the odd values, and it would have absolutely zero effect on its neighbors and their placement in the original list. The only way to detect this change is to iterate over every single value in the odd list, and make sure they are all still odd.

Therefore, the best you can possibly achieve is `O(n)`, since unless you inspect every value, I will be able to mutate the input in such a way that I change the outcome without your algorithm's detection.

Answer (score 2):

In case the answer is negative, you *must look at all elements at least once* to be sure, so the worst-case is indisputably O(n).

---

An easy O(n) time, O(1) space algorithm is possible by merging the sequences A[i] and target-B[LengthB-1-n] until you find equal elements.

E.g. (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8) and (0, 2, 8, 9) giving 9 is the same as a merge of (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8) and (0, 1, 7, 9).

Note: the reason of this "twist" is to turn the problem in a more classical, well-studied one.

Answer (score -2):

I think it's possible. If you consider the problem as searching a target value in a sorted matrix.

1. Every iteration, you have a `M x N` matrix `m`(m[i][j] = A[i]+B[j]), and select the center value `m[M/2][N/2]`.
2. Compared `m[M/2][N/2]` with target, you always exclude a `M/2 x N/2` sub-matrix.
3. Search remaining 3 `M/2 x N/2` sub-matrix repeatedly.

The algorithm complexity is O(log(m)+log(n)), the base of log is 4/3, O(1) space.

**The matrix is not really built.**

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int A[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
int B[] = {10,20,31,40,50,60,70,80,90};

int AResult, BResult;

int f(int ALeft, int ARight, int BLeft, int BRight, int target)
{
    if(ALeft > ARight || BLeft > BRight) return 0;

    int ACenterIndex = ALeft+(ARight-ALeft)/2;
    int BCenterIndex = BLeft+(BRight-BLeft)/2;
    int CenterValue = A[ACenterIndex]+B[BCenterIndex];

    if(CenterValue == target){
        AResult = ACenterIndex;
        BResult = BCenterIndex;
        return 1;
    }

    if(CenterValue < target){
        return f(ACenterIndex + 1, ARight, BLeft, BCenterIndex, target)
            || f(ACenterIndex + 1, ARight, BCenterIndex + 1, BRight, target)
            || f(ALeft, ACenterIndex, BCenterIndex + 1, BRight, target);
    }
    else{
        return f(ACenterIndex, ARight, BLeft, BCenterIndex - 1, target)
            || f(ALeft, ACenterIndex - 1, BLeft, BCenterIndex - 1, target)
            || f(ALeft, ACenterIndex - 1, BCenterIndex, BRight, target);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int M=9,N=9,target=111;
    AResult = BResult = -1;
    if(f(0,M-1,0,N-1,target)){
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n",A[AResult],B[BResult],target);
    }
    else{
        printf("not founed\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "select the center value", but I strongly suspect that that is itself a `O(n^2)` operation.  In any case, other answers are correct. There is no shortcut for searching the whole array once, which means there cannot be a better than `O(n)` algorithm.

Comment: I update the code in my answer. Notably, the matrix is not really built. When I search a value in M x N matrix, I always exclude 1/4 of the matrix.

Comment: @btilly Could you analyze the complexity of the code？

Comment: I think this is a really good attempt and probably the best we can ever come to a `O(logn)` solution, but I think the time complexity is `O(n)`. Since every call to `f` that doesn't satisfy the base case guarantees another 3 calls to `f`, the `kth` level of the recursion tree is `3^k`. The max depth of the tree is somewhere on the order of `O(logn)`, making the total number of calls to `f` `O(n)`.